# Some fishermen tell me I caught a Trout Salmon. Does this fish differ much from ordinary salmon?

Tags: fish, salmon, seafood

Like the title says, got a couple questions about the fish I just caught...

Firstly, is there anyway to confirm what type of fish this is? 'Ordinary salmon' or 'trout salmon'?

Lastly, does it differ much in taste from 'ordinary' salmon? I want to search for some good Salmon recipes but I want to be sure I'm looking at the right recipes for the right fish.

Cheers.

Answer (score 7):

I've had Salmon Trout.  They are a pink fleshed trout, that mimics the flavour of Salmon somewhat.

My favourite preparation is to do it as a Yerevan Trout.  Essentially Roast the fish filets, prepare the sauce - Lemon, Butter, Capers, Artichokes, and any pan juice you can get.  Serve beside your favourite rice.

Comment: trout and salmon are from the same family, so it makes sense that there are some types of trout that are more similar to salmon.

Comment: They're relatively common in the great lakes, where Salmon has been stocked for years.  I'm wondering if it's a natural hybrid.

Answer (score 2):

"Salmon Trout" or "Trout Salmon"? I've never heard of "Trout Salmon", but trout and salmon are closely related fish. It looks like [Salmon Trout](http://lewis-clark.org/content/content-article.asp?ArticleID=1931) could just be another name for [Rainbow Trout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_trout), so you should probably be looking at trout recipes instead of salmon recipes. "Trout" usually refers to a freshwater fish that lives in lakes and streams, where "salmon" usually refers to a saltwater fish that migrates into freshwater to breed. Culinarily speaking, "trout" is a smaller fish with white flesh, and "salmon" is larger, with pink flesh.

Answer (score 1):

Fish common names vary (sometimes TOO much) from place to place.

Salmon Trout is usually  *Salvelinus fontinalis*

The name usually comes from the meat color, but be aware that it is mainly a product of the little beast diet, and not genetically conditioned. So, depending on the habitat you may find fontinalis more or less "salmon-like".

Like this:

[image]

or this:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Steel head classification as members of the salmon family (Salmoniforms salmonidea, respectively the order and family) was changed in 1988, as approved by American Fisheries Society:  changed from:  Salmo gairoheri to become: Oncorhynchus mykiss, STEEL HEAD TROUT.  A fine multi-published scientist, avid fisherman, my father, contributed to this answer.

Comment: It's not clear how this post actually answers the question.

Comment: What does steel head trout have to do with "Trout Salmon". This is the bridge we are missing. If you are trying to say that "Trout Salmon" **is** steel head trout, please be more clear about this. Right now your answer doesn't make sense in the context of the question.

Comment: From a brief look, "salmon" refers to several things in the salmonidae family, which also includes trout. So... sure, this is probably all true, but it doesn't really seem like moving a species from one genus to another within that family really proves anything at all about what the common names for that species are. And Wikipedia lists plenty of subspecies, with common names, none of which are "salmon trout".